# Where can I see "who can see a button"?

Tags: profile, user-profile

I need a help, my issue is... A user can't see the button "Novo caso", but other user can see, where can I see where is configurate this permission?

This user can see the button
[image: this user can see the button]

This user can't see the button
[image: this user can't see the button]

I search in profile settings, but I don't see anything about.

Comment: is it a custom button? You should check the page layout (that is assigned to a profile). If it is the standard "new" button. You should check the profile permission in Case object

Comment: This is a custom button (I guess) and how can I know how is the page layout? Sorry for this asks, but I'm a newbie in Salesforce.

Comment: Isn't it the "New" standard button? If so, the user profile might not have access to Case creation.

Comment: It looks like a standard button, as it is in the listview screen and some people is seeing and other no. So, I suggest go to profile and see if the user has access to create case

Comment: another thing that helps, ask the user to log in in english to make sure what is the value. I do not remember if Novo(a) is translated in this way in Portuguese or it was a custom translation also.

Comment: Thanks guys, but already gaven the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like one user cannot create cases while the other can.

Look at both user records and click on their profiles. Scroll down and find the Standard Object Permissions section

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks dude, this is the my problem.

Answer (score 1):

The actions appears on Object home page comes through List View option in search layout for the object.

The step would be:- Setup--> Object Manager--> Select the Object --> Click on Search Layout for Classic--> You will see below options:-

[image]

Click on the drop down option against the List view and select edit. You will see below:-

[image]

You can identify weather button is Custom or Standard from here by checking where they have been added.

If it is Standard New Button, Check the profile of the user can't see the button. In profile, check the object permission